# How to Add Picture-In-Picture mode onTouch Drag Down

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, android-picture-in-picture

I am using [this Github project](https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/Android-VideoTube) for my app to play you tube videos using Youtube API.. I have the following code in my `onInitializationSuccess` method..

```
 @Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    this.player = player;
    player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
    player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo("I0D-fkypQQw");
    }
}
```

I coded this `YouTubePlayerView` to play in PIP mode in the following way :

```
enter_pip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //  Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PipActivity.class);
            //  startActivity(i);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
                //Trigger PiP mode
                try {
                    Rational rational = new Rational(youTubeView.getWidth(), youTubeView.getHeight());

                    PictureInPictureParams mParams =
                            new PictureInPictureParams.Builder()
                                    .setAspectRatio(rational)
                                    .build();

                    enterPictureInPictureMode(mParams);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "API 26 needed to perform PiP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });
}
```

The video successfully enters the PIP Mode, but the problem is the video stops after entering PIP mode , i want it to continue from where it was when not in PIP mode..

Please guide me on adding the picture-in-picture mode wherein the picture in picture mode should continue playing rather than stop.. I am looking for a youtube like PIP wherein the video plays at the bottom with Play/Pause Button and Close Button on its right..
[I am looking for a PIP as in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UomKu.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browse [this](https://github.com/moyokoo/YoutubeVideoSample) GitHub Link which completely meets your criteria of a DragDown Video...

To summarize the github project... 
use the `goMin()` method code ..in the YouTuDraggingView class which is as below:

```
    public void goMin(final boolean isDismissToMin) {
    nowStateScale = MIN_RATIO_HEIGHT;
    final float fullTop = Math.abs(mBackgroundViewWrapper.getMarginTop() - mRangeScrollY);
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(mBackgroundViewWrapper.getMarginTop(), mRangeScrollY);
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float value = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            mBackgroundView.setAlpha(isDismissToMin ? (value / fullTop) : 1);
            updateVideoView((int) value);
            if (value == mRangeScrollY) {
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = getLayoutParams();
                p.width = -2;
                p.height = -2;
                setLayoutParams(p);
                mCallback.status(STATUS_MIN);
            }
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.setDuration((long) (Math.abs((1 - mBackgroundViewWrapper.getMarginTop() / mRangeScrollY)) * rangeDuration)).start();
  }
```

and the goMax() to reverse...

```
    public void goMax() {
    if (nowStateScale == MIN_RATIO_HEIGHT) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.width = -1;
        params.height = -1;
        setLayoutParams(params);
    }


    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(mBackgroundViewWrapper.getMarginTop(), 0);
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            float value = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();

            updateVideoView((int) value);
            if (value == 0) {
                if (isLandscape()) {
                    goFullScreen();
                }
                mCallback.status(STATUS_MAX);
            }
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.setDuration((long) (mBackgroundViewWrapper.getMarginTop() / mRangeScrollY * rangeDuration)).start();

    nowStateScale = 1.0f;
  }
```

Hope this will help you...